# "Exercise validation failed: name: Path `name` is required."

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with this function:

```
create:(req,res)=>{
        
        var exerciseB = new Exercise({
            name:req.body.name,
            
        })
        

        exerciseB.save((err,exerciseB)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message);
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status:500,
                    message:err.message
                })
            }
            
            return res.status(201).json({
                status:200,
                message:"Exercise Created Successfully !"
            })
        })
    }
```

I have this error on Postman and on the console when I try POST-ing the route:

[image]

With JSON it works:

[image]

Why doesn't it accept data from as form-data? The thing is that I am also working on a front-end solution of this backend so if it doesn't accept data from a form it won't work in the front-end.

Comment: Do you have any middleware configured to parse form data? Give a [mre].

Comment: I am using this to parse data :  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));